# Ambiguous Redirection on shell script

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, redirect

I was trying to create a little shell script that allowed me to check the transfer progress when copying large files from my laptop's hdd to an external drive.
From the command line this is a simple feat using pv and simple redirection, although the line is rather long and you must know the file size (which is why I wanted the script):

console: du filename (to get the exact file size)

console: cat filename | pv -s FILE_SIZE -e -r -p > dest_path/filename

On my shell script I added *egrep "[0-9]{1,}" -o* to strip the filename and keep just the size numbers from the return value of du, and the rest should be straightforward.

```
#!/bin/bash
du $1 | egrep "[0-9]{1,}" -o
sudo cat $1 | pv -s $? -e -r -p > $2/$1
```

The problem is when I try to copy file12345.mp3 using this I get an ambiguous redirection error because egrep is getting the 12345 from the filename, but I just want the size.
Which means the return value from the first line is actually:

FILE_SIZE

12345

which bugs it.
How should I modify this script to parse just the first numbers until the first " " (space)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

To retain only the filesize from the du command output:

```
du $1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

(assuming the 1st field is the size of the file)

Add double quotes to your redirection to avoid the error:

```
sudo cat $1 | pv -s $? -e -r -p > "$2/$1"
```

This quoting is done since your `$2` contains spaces.

Comment: that does work on the command line (just returns the number) but I still get an ambiguous redirect using: pcopy NA-495-2013-03-14-Final.mp3 /media/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/ (FYI, pcopy is the script name) (edit: also getting ambiguous redirect without the last slash)

Comment: Can you please show us how you run the script? I mean to see especially how the arguments are passed to the script?

Comment: What happens if you break it down into steps. For example, use Guru's snippet to find the block size. And statically put this in your second line. Does it work when it's hard coded in?

Comment: Exactly how I showed on the last comment: pcopy filename.ext dest_path

Comment: @PaulCalabro you mean saving the return value of Guru's snippet on a variable and then using that variable on the cat / pv command or something else? I'm new to bash programming...

Comment: Pretty much. Run that command, passing in the file you want to copy. See what it gives you back for a value. THEN run the second line, but substitute the value for the variable you got from step 1. See if it works from there. Basically break it down into small steps and see where it fails.

Comment: it fails on line 3 /bin/pcopy: line 3: $2/$1: amiguous redirection

Comment: cat $1 | pv -s $? -e -r -p > "$2/$1" THIS WORKS. BUT, it's not showing the ETA or progress (so I guess it's not reading the size right). I tried doing SIZE=$? and then using -s SIZE on the pv command but it crashes: pv -s: integer argument expected

Comment: UPDATE:if I change the code to: du $1 | awk '{print $1}' echo "this is the size:" echo $? the last echo prints 0

Comment: UPDATE2: if I save the file size to a file size and then read it in-line using `cat size` after -s I get the progress but the percentage is all wacked because it completes at 100000% (it says 1000% when it means 1% and so it can't calculate the ETA yet)